Angular 14 - Testing with Jest for method private
I have this private method in my Angular component:
  private cacheValueChanges() {
    const cacheControl = this.form.get(CATALOG_INPUT.MAX_CACHE) as AbstractControl;
    this.subscriptions.add(
      cacheControl.valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
        if (value && this.isValidationAdded) {
          this.resetValidationFieldCacheForm(cacheControl);
        }
      })
    )
  }

It is a private method that is called from NgOnInit and is used to detect when the value in an input of a form called cache changes.
If the input has a value and isValidationAdded, which is a private attribute of the component, is true, another private method is called:
  private resetValidationFieldCacheForm(cacheControl: AbstractControl) {
    this.isValidationAdded = false;
    this.createActivityService.addValidateMaxCache(this.apiValidation, cacheControl, this.isValidationAdded);
    cacheControl.updateValueAndValidity({emitEvent: false});
  }

I need to test the private cacheValueChanges method in Jest and also resetValidationFieldCacheForm when the condition is met.
This is my test in Jest, but it is giving me an error:
describe('CreateActivityComponent', () => {
let createActivityService: CreateActivityService;

beforeEach(async () => {
await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [ CreateActivityComponent ],
  imports: [
    TranslateModule.forRoot(),
    HttpClientTestingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
  ],
})
.compileComponents();

fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CreateActivityComponent);
component = fixture.componentInstance;
createActivityService = TestBed.inject(CreateActivityService);

});

  describe('cacheValueChanges', () => {
    it('should reset validation field cache form when cache control value changes and validation is added', () => {
      const spyCreateActivity = jest.spyOn(createActivityService, 'addValidateMaxCache');

      component.ngOnInit();

      const cacheMaxControl = component.form.get(CATALOG_INPUT.MAX_CACHE) as AbstractControl;
      cacheMaxControl.setValue('200');

      expect(spyCreateActivity).toHaveBeenCalledWith({}, cacheMaxControl!, false);
    });
  });
});

Error:
 CreateActivityComponent › cacheValueChanges › should reset validation field cache form when cache control value changes and validation is added        

    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

    Expected: {}, {"_composedAsyncValidatorFn": null, "_composedValidatorFn": [Function anonymous], "_hasOwnPendingAsyncValidator": false, "_onChange": [], "_onCollectionChange": [Function anonymous], "_onDisabledChange": [], "_parent": {"_composedAsyncValidatorFn": null, "_composedValidatorFn": null, "_hasOwnPendingAsyncValidator": false, "_onCollectionChange": [Function anonymous], "_onDisabledChange": [Array], "_parent": null, "_pendingDirty": false, "_pendingTouched": false, "_rawAsyncValidators": null, "_rawValidators": null, "controls": [Object], "errors": null, "pristine": true, "status": "INVALID", "statusChanges": [EventEmitter_], "touched": false, "value": [Object], "valueChanges": [EventEmitter_]}, "_pendingChange": false, "_pendingDirty": false, "_pendingTouched": false, "_pendingValue": "200", "_rawAsyncValidators": null, "_rawValidators": [[Function required], [Function anonymous], [Function anonymous], [Function anonymous], [Function anonymous]], "defaultValue": null, "errors": null, "pristine": true, "status": "VALID", "statusChanges": {"__isAsync": false, "closed": false, "currentObservers": [Array], "hasError": false, "isStopped": false, "observers": [Array], "thrownError": null}, "touched": false, "value": "200", "valueChanges": {"__isAsync": false, "closed": false, "currentObservers": [Array], "hasError": false, "isStopped": false, "observers": [Array], "thrownError": null}}, false

    Number of calls: 0

      241 |       cacheMaxControl.setValue('200');
      242 |
    > 243 |       expect(spyCreateActivity).toHaveBeenCalledWith({}, cacheMaxControl!, false);
          |                                 ^
      244 |     });
      245 |   });

It seems that I am not passing the parameters correctly when I do:
expect(spyCreateActivity).toHaveBeenCalledWith({}, cacheMaxControl!, false);

What could be wrong? Thank you,

Number of calls: 0 the spy is never called. Are you missing a call to TestBed.configureTestingModule? See TestBed docs

Not because I have other tests of the same component that are working for me, I update the question to complete the test

I think it's because isValidationAdded is false and that's why the spy doesn't run, I'm trying to figure out how to mock isValidationAdded to be true

But I'm not sure that's it.
